# ant exec task output includes the args?

Tags: batch-file, ant, exec

In windows 8.1 when I run this, I get the exec command appended to the top of the output file.

```
<exec executable="cmd" os="Windows 8" spawn="false" dir="${basedir}" output="${build.out}" error="${build.err}">
    <arg value="/c"/>
    <arg line="${build.bat}" />
    <arg value="-p"/>
</exec>
```

The output file looks like this:

```
 C:\yaya\the_base_dir>node C:\yaya\haha\pjsCompile.js 
 //here begins the output I expected....
```

How do I remove the command from the output?  Why is it there?

If it is helpful, this is the build.bat:

```
 node C:\yaya\haha\pjsCompile.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `build.bat` to this:

```
@node C:\yaya\haha\pjsCompile.js
```

or to this:

```
@echo off
node C:\yaya\haha\pjsCompile.js
```